# some doubt in indicator function

Tags: real-analysis

The indicator function of a subset A of a set X is a function

${\displaystyle \mathbf {1} _{A}\colon X\to \{0,1\}} $ defined as follow

${\displaystyle \mathbf {1} _{A}(x):={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if }}x\in A,\\0&{\text{if }}x\notin A.\end{cases}}} $

Here Im not understanding the Red line statements and How  it is possible ?

[image]

Any  Hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried computing the sets in question, such as, $\{x : \mathbf{1}_U(x) > t\}$ for $U$ open and $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @SangchulLee how  can i compute ?

Comment: Are you asking why the indicator function of an open set is lower semicontinuous, or are you asking what is it about this fact concerning indicator functions that makes this fact important enough for the author to use the word "prototypical"?

Comment: @jasmine ask yourself what values $1_U(x)$ can take. What if $t\geq 1$? What if $1>t\geq 0$ ? And finally, what if $0> t$ ?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro im asking   why the indicator function of an open set is lower semicontinuous, ? vice versa  for  closed set also   upper  semi cont

Comment: @Jakobian if  $t \le 1$  then $1_U(x)=0$   Is its true ?

Comment: See the solution to Problem 1(ii) [here](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~zakeri/mat702/h4_sol.pdf)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfrov thanks u so much,...i will read now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\{ x : f(x) > t\}$ is simply the inverse image $f^{-1}((t, \infty))$. Obviously, this set is intimately related to the portion of the graph $y = f(x)$ which lies above the horizontal line $y = t$:

$\hspace{9em}$[image: Graphical explanation]

In the case of $f = \mathbb{1}_A$, this function takes value $1$ on $A$ and $0$ outside $A$, so

$$f^{-1}((t, \infty)) = \begin{cases}
\varnothing, & \text{if } t \geq 1; \\
A, & \text{if } 0 \leq t < 1; \\
X, & \text{if } t < 0.
\end{cases} \tag{*} $$

Visualizing this situation by drawing the graph of $f = \mathbf{1}_A$ may be helpful. For a more detailed solution, note that

- If $x \in A$, then $\mathbf{1}_A(x) = 1$, and so, $\mathbf{1}_A(x) > t$ holds if and only if $1 > t$.
- If $x \notin A$, then $\mathbf{1}_A(x) = 0$, and so, $\mathbf{1}_A(x) > t$ holds if and only if $0 > t$.

From this,

1. If $t \geq 1$, then neither of $1 > t$ nor $0 > t$ is satisfies, and so, $\{ x : \mathbf{1}_A(x) > t\} = \varnothing$.
2. If $1 > t \geq 0$, then $1 > t$ holds but $0 > t$ does not hold. This gives $\{ x : \mathbf{1}_A(x) > t\} = A$.
3. If $t < 0$, then both $1 > t$ and $0 > t$ is true, and so, $\{ x : \mathbf{1}_A(x) > t\} = X$.

This proves $\text{(*)}$. In case $A$ is open, $\text{(*)}$ also tells that $\{ x : \mathbf{1}_A(x) > t\}$ is open for any $t$. Therefore $\mathbf{1}_A$ is l.s.c.

Comment: thanks u  @Sangchul For  upper semi continious   can  u give  me  any hints ?

Comment: @jasmine, The argument will be completely analogous, with due modifications. Is there any problem implementing the same idea? Or, alternatively, you can check that $f$ is u.s.c. if and only if $1-f$ is l.s.c., and then check that $1-\mathbf{1}_A = \mathbf{1}_{X\setminus A}$. Then given the answer above, the result is obvious since a set is closed iff its complements is open.

Comment: No  its oks @Sangchul       i forget to take complement

Comment: @SangchulLee Can I ask you a question? Recall that if $t < 0, f^{−1}((t,∞)) = X$. Why is $X$ open if $A$ is open. Thanks!

Comment: @Smith i think u tag me first......see if $t<0$,then indicator function have only two choice either $1$ or $ 0$ both according to the given condition  it cover both $0$ and $1$ ..Now  u r asking that   X is open if A is open  because open map to open  so  here only open image are only $ \{1\}$ and$ \{0\}$

Comment: @jasmine Sorry, I tagged the wrong person so I deleted my previous post. But if you can answer my question that will be great. I still don't really understand what you mean by open map to open. Do you mean the indicator function is an open map? I also don't understand why {1} and {0} are open images. Thanks!